# Keras predict() doesn't work as expected for a future timestep

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to do some LSTM time-series prediction for **one** timestep ahead using Keras. But when looking at examples on the web or implementing it myself it doesn't predict the next timestep but just predicts the current timestep which is no prediction. Shouldn't be the prediction one timestep ahead the test-data? See here what I mean:

[image]

I'm using:

```
self.model.predict(data)
```

Or is this intended and you have to manually shift your prediction array for one index which makes the prediction really bad.

Comment: If on training you're giving it the (x-1) previous timesteps and training it to predict the x-th value, then at test time it will predict the x-th of the input sequence. Not fully sure I understand what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking wrong. The problem is that the testdata get's splitted into samples and labels. If there is for example a window with 10, we have 9 samples and 1 label. Therefore the last value is missing for predicting a real-world future timestep on the last window. I have to create a third samples subset (next to samples, labels) which is shifted by 1 index and will be used to predict values so it's a real prediction.